# Data not being sent Axio post request from React Native to Spring Boot API

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, react-native, post, axios

When I am trying to make axio post request from React native to my Spring Boot API, my data is not being sent?

Here is my code in `apiReq` function:

```js
const apiReq = () => {
  return (axios.post('http://{IP address}:8082/api/login', {

    headers: {
      "Accept": 'application/json',
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "password": "#####",
      "username": "abcd.gmail.com"
    })
  })
    .then(response => {

      console.log(response.data.responseMessage.errorCode);

    })
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
  )

}
```

Comment: When i am seeing the error log in spring boot app it is as follows: Loading User Details for User: NONE_PROVIDED        \\ I think  which means it did'nt receive any data

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you don't use JSON stringfy. Also, I use axios like that.

```
const body = {
      password: "#####",
      username: "abcd.gmail.com"
    }
const options = {
    headers: {
          "Accept": 'application/json',
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}

axios.post('http://{IP address}:8082/api/login', body, options)
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: it is giving me thefollowing error : Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0): ReferenceError : Cant find variable : Error

Comment: Sorry, I forgot my some code blocks. Please, try again. I fixed it.